# How can I fix my Debian's /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: linux, debian, startup, system-recovery

I just need to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in my otherwise-functional Debian installation, but I can't boot up because it gets stuck at "Configuring network interfaces". So how can I access this file without booting up? Do I need a Live USB?

I'm using the `amd64` port of Debian 7.8.

Comment: what version of Debian?

Comment: `debian-7.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a live environment for this. You just need to boot into a rescue environment, which is easy.

When GRUB comes up, hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key, so that you can edit the kernel command-line. Find the line that begins with "linux", use the arrow keys to move down to the end of it, and type `single` (with a space before it). Then hit either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> (or <kbd>F10</kbd>, I can't remember) to boot.

This will drop you into a recovery shell. From there, just type `nano /etc/network/interfaces`, edit the file, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to exit, and type `exit` to boot.

Comment: Ohh well, thank you so much! I'm new to linux and reinstalled my debian completely new :) I can use that further ;)

Comment: @8m47x sure thing! if it helps you remember, `single` stands for "Single User Mode", where the only user is the superuser, `root`.

Comment: @8m47x since you're new to GNU/Linux, I'll also point out that (unlike Windows) _usually_, you can fix your problems without reinstalling. just ask on something like this site and be patient :)

Comment: This is awsome! I'm so glad to be in this community!